# Berkeley Parser English - different results online vs offline

Tags: nlp

I am using the Berkeley parser for English, from [here](https://github.com/slavpetrov/berkeleyparser). This seems to give me different results than their online [demo](http://tomato.banatao.berkeley.edu:8080/parser/parser.html).

For ex, consider the sentence:

`I am a platinum member. I want someone to fix this for me immediately.`

Running the parser on my machine gives me this parse tree (which is incorrect):
[image]

While running it through the demo I get this (which is correct):
[image]

Can someone point out why is there a difference here? The parser download has one english grammar file only, `eng_sm6.gr`, so it cannot be a wrong grammar file. Can this be a problem with a commandline switch? This is what I am running:
`java -jar BerkeleyParser-1.7.jar -gr eng_sm6.gr`

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons coming to my mind regarding this situation:

- they might have used a different grammar in online version
- they might have splitted the sentences before parsing and merged sentences into the root node in the online version

You may want to split sentences beforehand and then parse the sentences individually as well. Statistical parsers are trained with sentences. To my knowlegde, Berkeley Parser is an unlexicalized parser which is also trained with sentences, yet it may be more complicated to parse more tokens for it. As you can see in your outputs, the term *immediately* is pos-tagged as a noun; so you can give it a try to split the sentences first then parse and see how it goes after.

Cheers,

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and that seems to work for now. I stitch the parse trees together later; thanks!

Comment: you are welcome, thanks for the feedback and glad it helped!